# Display Contacts List (Contact Name, Number, Image* if possible) In a list view using Base Adapter.

Tags: arraylist, android-contacts, baseadapter

**I Browse some Base adapter tuts and did this, I don't know how to get the contacts set to the list can any one explain what I missed**

Here is the code:

```
class  SingleRow{
String name;
String number;
int image;
SingleRow(String name,String number){
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}

}
```

**I used SingleRow as a inner class** and here is my custom addapter

```
public class PranzAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
Context c;

PranzAdapter(Context context){
    c = context;

    list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();

    String[] names = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME};
    String[] number= new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
    for (int position=0; position<names.length; position++)
    {

       list.add(new SingleRow(names[position],number[position])) ;
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View row =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,null,false);
    TextView name= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView number = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    SingleRow temp = list.get(position);

     name.setText(temp.name);
     number.setText(temp.number);

     return row;
 }
 }
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setAdapter(new PranzAdapter(this));

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);

    }

}
```